# How to mass prepend text to file names?

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal, sed

Lets say I have a directory full of `.md` files all named various things. Lets say I wanted to prepend "test" to the front of each file name. So for example: file `a.md`, `b.md`, and `c.md` would become `test - a.md`, `test - b.md`, and `test - c.md`.

How would I accomplish this via command line?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

One-liner that can be easily typed straight from the terminal:

```
for f in *.md; do mv "$f" "test - $f"; done
```

Or rewritten on separate lines instead using semicolons:

```
for f in *.md
do
    mv "$f" "test - $f"
done
```

### Exposition

Syntax of `for` (in `sh`):

```
for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
```

Here, our `NAME` is `f` and our `WORDS` are all files in the current directory matching `*.md`. So the variable `$f` will be be substituted with each file matching `*.md`.

So for `a.md`:

```
mv "$f" "test - $f"
```

becomes

```
mv "a.md" "test - a.md"
```

The quotes are important because the each filename `$f` might contain spaces. Otherwise `mv` would think each word was a separate file. For example, if there were no quotes, and there's a file called `Foo Bar.md`, it would translate as:

```
mv Foo Bar.md test - Foo Bar.md
```

which would not work as intented. But by wrapping `$f` in quotes, it makes sense:

```
mv "Foo Bar.md" "test - Foo Bar.md"
```

Noting the syntax of `for`, you could also rename a subset of all the `*.md` files by naming each explicitly:

```
for f in a.md b.md d.md; do mv "$f" "Test - $f"; done
```

Or using shell expansion:

```
for f in {a,b,d}.md; do mv "$f" "Test - $f"; done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see. Thanks!

Comment: Great, served well for renaming all files to have .yaml extension, for f in ./*; do mv "$f" "$f.yaml"; done

Comment: Great, thanks! For appending to the end of a filename but before the file extension, I did: `filename="${f%.*}"; mv "$filename.md" "$filename textToAppend.md"` inside the loop. I made use of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/17616747

Answer (score 11):

If you have `prename`...

```
prename 's/^/test - /' *.md
```

Using ordinary shell commands:

```
for file in *.md; do
    mv "$file" "test - $file"
done
```

Comment: How do I get `prename` ?

Comment: Seems to be preinstalled for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Have you tried your package manager (ie., `sudo apt-get install`)?

Answer (score 7):

`mmv`[1](http://ss64.com/bash/mmv.html),[2](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/mmv-copy-append-link-move-multiple-files-under-linux-shell-bash-by-wildcard-patterns-p5/) is also a very nice tool for such a task, applied to the current job, it would be

```
mmv '*.md' 'test - #1.md'
```

Of course, if you only want to add "test - " to a.md, b.md and c.md, but not a1.md, something like

```
mmv '?.md' 'test - #1.md'
```

would be more appropriate.

I can really suggest it, especially if you have many such problems.

If you are additionally looking for a graphical interface, try [gprename](http://gprename.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a for loop, which will fail on spaces unless you redefine the IFS variable, I would recommend using a while loop combined with find. The following will work when run from the same directory as the files

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.md' | while read -r file; do
    file=$(basename $file)
    mv "$file" "test - $file"
done
```

the "basename" line is in there so that find will print the file name only - without path components which would make the rename operation break.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I want  to implement in Automator a way to prepend text to file names. How to modify this code to just apply the preprend operation on $@? (without any specific extension)? Thanks!

for f in *.md
do
    mv "$f" "test - $f"
done

Comment: Have a look at this: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_arg_in_.24.2A

Answer (score 3):

I know it's really late, but if anyone else is looking for something like this, then this worked for me:

```
rename '' 'name -' *.md
```

Comment: simple and straight-forward

Answer (score 0):

If you have `zsh` available you could use `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -w '*' 'test - $1'
```

You can test the command with:

```
zmv -wn '*' 'test - $1'
```

- `-n` means dry-run, i.e. only show what will happen.
- `-w` implicitly puts parenthesis around wildcards, makes backreferences work.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, adding "Prepend text - " to all files in folder:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/^/Prepend\ text\ \-\ /')"; done;
```

Comment: This is a super-long way of writing `for i in *; do mv "$i$" "Prepend text - $i"; done`